# c# ExcelDNA Passing User Class to Macro Restricted?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I'm using ExcelDNA to build a ribbon button which will retrieve SQL data then populate a new sheet by calling a macro via the event handler.  If I pass a string all is well (MyMethod1).  If I pass a user class (MyMethod2) I'm getting a type mismatch exception.  Is passing a user class via event handler restricted?

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Main : ExcelRibbon
{
    public override string GetCustomUI(string RibbonID)
    {
        return @"
<customUI xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui'>
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id='tab1' label='MyTab'>
        <group id='group1' label='Pass Data'>
            <button id='Button1' label='Button1' onAction='MyMethod1'/>
            <button id='Button2' label='Button2' onAction='MyMethod2'/>
            <button id='HideMe1' label='Hide Me1' visible='false' onAction='RunTagMacro' tag='MyMacro1'/>
            <button id='HideMe2' label='Hide Me2' visible='false' onAction='RunTagMacro' tag='MyMacro2'/>            </group >
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>";
    }
    public void MyMethod1(IRibbonControl control)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MyMethod1 - triggered");
        Excel.Application xlapp = (Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
        xlapp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, xlapp, new object[] { "MyMacro1", "MyParm" });
    }
    public static void MyMacro1(string arg1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(arg1);
    }
    public void MyMethod2(IRibbonControl control)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MyMethod2 - triggered");
        Mapper xclMapper = new Mapper();
        Excel.Application xlapp = (Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
        xlapp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        null, xlapp, new object[] { "MyMacro2", xclMapper });
    }
            public static void MyMacro2(Mapper arg1)
    {
        Mapper.RowModel parm1 = arg1.RowModels[1];
        MessageBox.Show(parm1.UserLabel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copying [Govert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44264/govert)'s [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/p-LIG-RvUgA) on the Excel-DNA mailing-list for people who find this via search engines:

> The types that `Application.Run` will support as parameters are limited,
>   and does not include CLR references or general COM objects.
>
> One approach would be to have an internal dictionary that has a key ->
>   object mapping and pass the key to the macro through the
>   `Application.Run` call.
>
> -Govert

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/p-LIG-RvUgA